# CREATE DATABASE from template copying only some tables's data

Tags: postgresql

I need to create several new databases using one of our customer's database as a template. The following works just fine:

```
> CREATE DATABASE new_customer
>     ENCODING 'LATIN1' 
>     LC_COLLATE 'pt_BR.ISO-8859-1' 
>     LC_CTYPE 'pt_BR.ISO-8859-1' 
>     TABLESPACE = new_customer_tablespace
>     TEMPLATE old_customer
>     OWNER = postgres
>     ;
```

However, I also need to "clean" the new database afterwards, dropping/recreating several - but not all - tables so that the new customer won't see the old one's private data. Currently, this is taking me quite a while per database, and I wonder if there's an easier way to do this.

I considered creating such a template, but since I'll need to keep this template up-to-date with the changes we do to other databases, I'd have to recreate it every time I want another database, which kind of defeats the purpose of doing this in the first place.

I also considered creating a dump from the old database using `--exclude-table-data=TABLE` option. The problems with this are that dumping first takes forever, and also the dump itself occupies a lot of disk space by creating a file that I'll just have to erase after the creation is completed.

Is there a better, simpler way to do this?

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.2 on an AWS HREL 7 instance.

Comment: You can pipe the output from your pg_dump directly into pg_restore to save overhead of writing the backup to disk and reading it back later, which might make a big difference if you are limited on iops or you could use a foreign data wrapper to copy data from one db to the other (not sure if 9.2 supports this, documentation is not online as 9.2 is not supported anymore).

Comment: What do you mean 9.2 isn't supported anymore? This is Red Hat 7's version... Shouldn't it be not only supported but also stabler than current 9.6 version?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.2 is indeed quite old. PostgreSQL supports versions for 5 years, but beyond that it's just the support which is offered by Red Hat. Also it might be "stable", but it does not mean that it has any new features included - for many people PostgreSQL is mature and stable enough that they don't have to wait 5+ years to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and fastest way is to create a template database.

True, you'll have to update it whenever you change the data definition, but you already have to do that with all the existing database, so applying the changes to one more database shouldn't hurt.

If you want to go the `pg_dump` way, dump with the `-s` option, that will be much faster. There is also the `--exclude-table-data` option to exclude the data only for certain tables, but that might be cumbersome with many tables.

Comment: The main problem with the template solution is the risk of "forgetting" to update something - we've had that happening before, with pretty bad results... But I do agree it's the fastest way to do it. `pg_dump -s` isn't quite what I'm looking for, though, as I do need to bring _some_ data with the dump - I'd say 30~50% of the original database. I am, however,  looking to remove data from hundreds of tables (maybe a thousand?)

Comment: I see. I have edited the answer to mention `--exclude-table-data` - that might be an option.

Comment: @JorgeFreitas: how do you manage your schema migrations? Sounds if you need a more strict deployment process for that if you are "forgetting" to update some things

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name to be honest, I'm still figuring this out... I'm not really an expert when it comes down to SQL, I'm just trying my hardest. The way I do our DBs updates right now is to create an SQL file, then diligently connect to each and every database we have and run this file to update them one by one. And about migration... Well, we just tried that with a dump only to find out there are tens of GBs we don't really need that were coming and taking both space and time to manage... Is there a better way to update multiple databases at once?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe in the end, the `--exclude-table-data` approach was the best one for me. Although my command does have over 5.000 characters, it does work as I intended it to, and having to delete the file afterwards isn't that big of a deal, especially when considering my dump now has 25% of the full dump, so it doesn't take as long to create.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use your backup which you hopefully already have.

Do your backups using the custom format. If you need to restore a database, you can create an index of the backup (using the --list option), de-select the items you do not want in the new database, and then use the --use-list option to create the new database from your backup.

This way you also gain confidence that your backup works, because you do a restore once in a while.

Oh, and this also works with version 9.2.